# Filter data from Object Array using two conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist

I have an object array. in every object contains property category name and categoryId and subcategory list which is array.i want to filter data based on both name and subcategoryList value.this is my sample array

```
var statesWithFlags = [
    { subCategoriesList: ['Badges and dentures', 'Cerezens', 'Dental implants'], categoryId: 1, categoryName: "Dental" },
    { subCategoriesList: ['Badges and dentures44', 'Dental implants'], categoryId: 2, categoryName: "Dermatology" },
    { subCategoriesList: ['Badges and dentures', 'Cerezens', 'Dental implants222'], categoryId: 3, categoryName: "Eye" },
    { subCategoriesList: ['Badges and dentures', 'Cerezens', 'Dental implants', 'Cerezens'], categoryId: 4, categoryName: "Ayurvedic" }
  ]
```

currently, I'm using something like this.this is only works for categoryName property. I want this to modified for the category list as well.

```
this.statesWithFlags.filter(v => v.categoryName.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1)).slice(0, 10))
```

Comment: what is `term` and what is the expected output?

Comment: thank you for concern @brk I found the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether `.some` of the `subCategoriesList` have the string your searching for, or if the `categoryName` has it:

```
const termLower = term.toLowerCase();
this.statesWithFlags.filter(v => (
  v.subCategoriesList.some(subCat => subCat.toLowerCase().includes(termLower))
  || v.categoryName.toLowerCase().includes(termLower)
))
  .slice(0, 10);
```